# Docker : ' -ti ' argument

Tags: docker

Build an image based on the `Dockerfile`:

```
docker image build .
```

The result of above is

```
docker run --rm -ti <IMAGE_ID>
```

`--rm` : `If instead you’d like Docker to automatically clean up the container and remove the file system when the container exits, you can add the --rm flag` src : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

What does the `-ti` argument achieve ?

Comment: Try removing one or both `t` and `i` and see what happens :)

Comment: `-ti` = `-t`+`-i` = `--tty`+`--interactive`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-it` is shorthand for `-i -t`

By [Docker Run docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground)

> -i Keep STDIN open even if not attached 
>   -t Allocate a pseudo-tty

Which means, **t** for open a shell terminal (telewriter) and **i** listen to standard input.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically just `-i` and `-t` which is mostly written as [`-it`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground).

`-i`:

> Keep STDIN open even if not attached

`-t`:

> Allocate a pseudo-TTY

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 1):

It's most common way of using Docker containers, so you can actually use them to execute some of your commands.

`i` stands for `interactive` and it's accepts and responds on your input using STDIN.
`t` is for you to have `terminal` - it's combined with `i` so you can actually put your input there.

Check more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/what-are-pseudo-terminals-pty-tty).

Comment: I'd question the *"most common"* line. In most cases, you only do this when debugging stuff